# Connecting to Cloud SQL with Private IP from GCE or GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to a Postgres database (CloudSQL) from a pod deployed in a GoogleCompute cluster, with a private IP, but I get only connection timeout errors.

I setup the GCP cluster with the following:

```
gcloud beta container clusters create "gcp-cluster" --zone "europe-west1-b" --no-enable-basic-auth --cluster-version "1.13.6-gke.13" --machine-type "n1-standard-1" --image-type "COS" --disk-type "pd-ssd" --disk-size "20" --metadata disable-legacy-endpoints=true --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice" --num-nodes "2" --enable-stackdriver-kubernetes --enable-ip-alias --network "projects/XXX/global/networks/default" --subnetwork "projects/XXX/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/default" --default-max-pods-per-node "110" --enable-autoscaling --min-nodes "2" --max-nodes "20" --addons HorizontalPodAutoscaling,HttpLoadBalancing --enable-autoupgrade --enable-autorepair --maintenance-window "19:00"
```

Then I deployed a wildfly pointing to the postgres database IP address (DB created in the same zone/region), but I get only connection timeout. After have enabled a public IP address with source  0.0.0.0/0, I can get a connection.

Any idea to work with private IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours I got my connection by enabling CloudSql access scope for the VM instances.

Answer (score 1):

Private IP means accessing Cloud SQL through a [Virtual Private Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc) (VPC). You have to use a resource (in this case, GCE instance) that is also on that VPC to be able to reach it. See the [environment requirements](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc) page of the Private IP docs.

Note for future readers: It's a really bad idea to whitelist `0.0.0.0/0` on a Public IP address. This essentially allows the entire internet to attempt to connect to your instance, and should not be left enabled for any extended period of time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used 0.0.0.0/0 just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Your gke cluster is in europe-west1-b. Assuming that you use the default network, you must enable Private Google Access for europe-west1 subnet. Click on the subnet to view details and edit it if required to set **Private Google Access** to "**On**".